# Как скачать Apache?

Tags: apache

Подскажите нормальную статью по скачиванию и установке apache. А ещё лучше видео, но только чтоб это была новая версия. Вот с [этой страницы](http://httpd.apache.org/download#apache24) можно скачать сервер? Я на какую ссылку не нажму, пустая страница вылазит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно, надо полагать, под винду? Сейчас ссылки с http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi ведут на

`http://apache.claz.org//httpd/binaries/win32/`

Comment: а какой файл именно файл скачивать надо?

Comment: Полноценный (с поддержкой SSL) и наиболее свежий вариант:  
httpd-2.2.22-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8t.msi

Answer (score 0):

Я ставил Apache пользуясь этой [статьей](http://ab-w.net/PHP/server_set.php). Все работает прекрасно.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sdelaysite.com/php/php-2 - Вот тут есть подробное видео как ставить Apache, MySQL, PHP и phpmyadmin!

Answer (score 0):

В командной строке выполнить

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```